# Extract Value from HTML using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm retrieving a HTML page using cURL. The html page has a table like this.

```
<table class="table2" style="width:85%; text-align:center">
<tr>
<th>Refference ID</th>
<th>Transaction No</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Operator</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Slot</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>130717919020ffqClE0nRaspoB</td>
<td>8801458920369</td>
<td>Purchase</td>
<td>Visa</td>
<td>50</td>
<td>20130717091902413</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the only table in that HTML page. I need to extract Refference ID & Slot using PHP.

But no idea how that can be done.

**EDIT:**
This [one](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/275068-extract-data-from-html-table/) helped me a lot.

Comment: couple of keywords for you, xpath, simplehtmldom, phpquery

Comment: This may also help http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: @Jose David Garcia Llanos: I would like to see how you do that using `stripos`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '<table class="table2" style="width:85%; text-align:center">
<tr>
<th>Refference ID</th>
<th>Transaction No</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Operator</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Slot</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>130717919020ffqClE0nRaspoB</td>
<td>8801458920369</td>
<td>Purchase</td>
<td>Visa</td>
<td>50</td>
<td>20130717091902413</td>
</tr>
</table>';

preg_match_all('/<td>([^<]*)<\/td>/', $str, $m);

$reference_id = $m[1][0];
$slot = $m[1][5];
```

Comment: Although it can work, use of regular expressions to parse HTML code is highly discouraged. A proper HTML parser should be used. PHP comes with inbuilt parsers, such as the DOMDocument class.

Comment: @Shane Of course! I am just as guilty as the next guy though for "getting things done" - even sometimes against best practices. Depending on the size and importance of the project, this could be an absurd answer.

Comment: I am also guilty of this. It does work. However I thought I should just put it out there that it's discouraged. If it's some small script or something like that, by all means drop convention. But if this is something that is intended to be used in a production environment, I suggest one would look at the proper way to do things ;)

Comment: You are doing it wrong! Your code is error-prone and hard to maintain. Period.

Comment: I came here because I was about to show in another question that it is easy to use the search box like "PHP extract values from HTML" and they will find the right answer. Unfortunately this post was found. Don't take it personal!

Answer (score 1):

A regex based solution like the accepted answer is *not* the right way to extract information from HTML documents.

Use a `DOMDocument` based solution like this instead:

```
$str = '<table class="table2" style="width:85%; text-align:center">
<tr>
<th>Refference ID</th>
  ...
<th>Slot</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>130717919020ffqClE0nRaspoB</td>
  ...
<td>20130717091902413</td>
</tr>
</table>';

// Create a document out of the string. Initialize XPath
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Query the values in a stable and easy to maintain way using XPath
$refResult = $selector->query('//table[@class="table2"]/tr[2]/td[1]');
$slotResult = $selector->query('//table[@class="table2"]/tr[2]/td[6]');

// Check if the data was found
if($refResult->length !== 1 || $slotResult->length !== 1) {
   die("Data is corrupted");
}

// XPath->query always returns a node set, even if 
// this contains only a single value.
$refId = $refResult->item(0)->nodeValue;
$slot = $slotResult->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo "RefId: $refId, Slot: $slot", PHP_EOL;
```